# Informatica 8.6.0 with Netezza database

Tags: informatica-powercenter

Our target is a [Netezza](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/netezza/) database. Our source is a .csv file. We are using Informatica 8.6.0.

In the workflow manager, in the Relational Connection Browser, I am not able to get Netezza as the Database.

Do need to add any drivers? How do i get it to show up?

Comment: Is there no *Netezza* entry in the *Select Type* drop-down list **OR** no connection in the *Objects* list?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your Netezza server properties inside Informatica's ODBC directory, something like below

```
[NZ_CONNECTION_NAME]
Driver                = /opt/informatica/nz/lib/libnzsqlodbc3.so
Description           = NetezzaSQL ODBC
Servername            = nz_host_name_or_ip_address
Port                  = 5480
Database              = group_generic_dims
Username              = nz_db_username
Password              = nz_db_password
CancelAsFreeStmt      = false
CommLog               = false
Ksqo                  = false
Lie                   = false
Optimizer             = false
Parse                 = false
PreFetch              = 256
Protocol              = 7.0
ReadOnly              = false
ShowSystemTables      = false
Socket                = 16384
DateFormat            = 1
TranslationDLL        =
```

Make sure you're pointing to the right libnzsqlodbc.so file (the driver).

Comment: I would assume that installing the Netezza driver/plugin for informatica on the box will do all of this automatically. In any case, this manual effort will accomplish this nonetheless.

Comment: @learn4living the driver comes with a template with all the fields above but you will need to change the dummy values with real ones.